# Scoreboard stat drinking water

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im trying to make a thirst thing, but I cant make a stat which tests for a player drinking water. Any ways around this?

Comment: I'm making a `thirst thing` too, with `bossbar`. How're you doing yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user [slove211](http://www.minecraftforum.net/members/slove211) asked a similar question in [this comment](http://www.minecraftforum.net/comments/8683756) on [this post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/351297-command-block-test-for-help) on the [Minecraft Forum](http://minecraftforum.net/). The user [Skylinerw](http://www.minecraftforum.net/members/Skylinerw) answered him in [this comment](http://www.minecraftforum.net/comments/8683757). His answer was

> ### Quote from Skylinerw:
>
> You can use the following, though this would only work if the player completely drinks the water bottle. Also note that all potion items drunk (including potions thrown) will increment this value, as there is no way to differentiate between Damage values for stats:
>
> /scoreboard objectives add DRINKWATER stat.useItem.minecraft.potion
>
> So each time the player completely drinks a water bottle, their "DRINKWATER" score will increment by 1.

As Skylinerw stated, this will also get incremented by throwing a potion or drinking a potion, unfortunately there is no way around this.

Good luck!

Comment: Well, who says potions don't make you less thirsty?